# How to manipulate multiple directives in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I've just started using Angular 2 a few weeks ago and I'm kinda stuck with something here, so I may need some help. The thing is that I would like to create custom components in Ionic 2 that could be reusable. For example, if I decide to create a custom button with different sizes.

`<btn-custom sm-size rounded> </btn-custom>`

Where `sm-size` and `rounded` would inject specific CSS codes into my component. I figured that they're Attribute directives, but I still can't see how I can manipulate it. Could someone please help me understanding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Input()`s go get whether attributes are set or not, and you can use `@HostBinding()` to apply style or class bindings to the host element and `[style.xxx]`, `[ngStyle]`, `[class.xxx]`, and `[ngClass]` to apply styles and classes to content of your component:

```ts
@Component({
  template: `
<button [style.with.px]="smSize ? 250 : 150">click me</button>
<!-- or -->
<button [ngClass]="smSize ? 'big' : 'small'">click me</button>
})
class ButtonCustom {

  private _smSize:boolean;

  get isSmSize:boolean() {
    return this._smSize;
  }

  @Input() 
  set smSize(value:any) {
    this._smSize = value != 'false'; // treat everything as `true` except `'false'`
  }

  @HostBinding('style.border-radius')
  borderRadius:number = 0;

  private _rounded:boolean;

  get isRounded:boolean() {
    return this._rounded;
  }
  @Input() 
  set rounded(value:any) {
    this._rounded = value != 'false'; // treat everything as `true` except `'false'`
    this.borderRadius = this._rounded ? 3 : 0;
  }
}
```

The setters are a way to get the info about whether an attribute is set without a value

```ts
<btn-custom smSize rounded>
```

vs

```ts
<btn-custom smSize="50" rounded="true">
<btn-custom [smSize]="50" [rounded]="true">
```

Comment: Sorry, but, are you sure this may work? `<button [ngClass]="smSize : 'big' : 'small'">click me</button>`cuz when I tried to use it I got the following message: "Unhandled Promise rejection: Quotes are not supported for evaluation! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Quotes are not supported for evaluation!(…) Error: Quotes are not supported for evaluation!"

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. The first `:` should be a `?`, like in the line before.

Comment: Oh yeah, now it worked. But I'm still a bit confused about how it works. Considering that I want to use this format `[ngClass]="smSize ? 'big' : 'small'"` to choose which class I want to set up: either big or small. Will I just need to pass which class I want to use in my HTML? Like `<btn-custom smSize="small">`

Comment: If `smSize` contains a class name, then yes. If you use `<btn-custom smSize rounded>`, then you don't pass a class name. I assumed `smSize` is either `true` or `false`.

Comment: Oops, I just realized that there is a problem with the code above. Setting two buttons with `<btn-custom btnSize="sm-size" ></btn-custom>` and `<btn-custom btnSize="md-size" ></btn-custom>` to test if they will receive different classes, using as template `<button [ngClass]="btnSize ? 'sm-size' : 'md-size'">click me</button>` it always sets `md-size` as class. Am I using something wrong?

Comment: You are mixing up approaches. You are passing a class name to `btnSize` but then use `ngClass` like it was set to `true` or `false`. It should be `<button [ngClass]="btnSize"`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the ngStyle directive here, to tell the component the additional styles to apply.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgStyle-directive.html
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngStyle

Using the Style directive you can inject styles.

If you have predefined classes then ngClass would work best, which looks like what you need:

```
<btn-custom [ngClass]="{'sm-size rounded' : true}">...</btn-custom>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html

This guide will help:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngClass

Comment: Just to ensure that I understood your answer, using ngClass I'll need to write which classes I want to use in every component I include, for instance, button 1: `[<btn-custom [ngClass]="{'sm-size rounded': true}">...</btn-custom>` and button 2: `<btn-custom [ngClass]="{'md-size' : true}">...</btn-custom>`. Is this right?